# Can I source more than 2 R script in global.R(Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I currently have a few script that I am required to source into global.R, so that I can draw the data that are tidied into my server.R, so as to plot the necessary graph.

However I am encountering an error when I source 2 script, where the second script such as title.R cannot be open. However, if I choose only 1 script to be sourced, I can run it.

I would need help to source more than 1 script into my global environment.

Thanks.

```
> shiny::runApp('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/')
Warning in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'title.R': No such file or directory
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

Here is the code:

```
source('abc.R',echo=FALSE)
source('title.R',echo=FALSE)
```

I have tried sourcing directly from directory, but it cant work as well.
for example:

```
source("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Folder/abc.R",echo=FALSE)
source("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Folder/title.R",echo=FALSE)
```

Both the file are similar. But within it, it sources another script in the another directory which is different from the global.R,server.R,ui.R directory
abc.R

```
setwd("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/R/Item1")

source('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/R/Folder1/subFolder1/ReadData1.R',echo=FALSE)
#To be Data frame so as to subset it.
Item1QE<-data.frame(QE)
Item1QI<-data.frame(QI)
Item1VE<-data.frame(VE)
Item1VI<-data.frame(VI)
```

title.R

```
setwd("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/R/Item2")

source('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/R/Folder1/subFolder2/ReadData.R',echo=FALSE)
#To be Data frame so as to subset it.
Item2QE<-data.frame(QE)
Item2QI<-data.frame(QI)
Item2VE<-data.frame(VE)
Item2VI<-data.frame(VI)
```

Comment: It is no problem to source multiple scripts (I have an app with 7 sourced scripts). The error you get is that shiny does not find the script, maybe a typo in the path to your file? Do you use relative paths?

Comment: show how you 'source' the file

Comment: Have you tried sourcing the script in `server.R`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik yes i did, however the same problem persists. I can only source the first script/file, the second script produce the same error.

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example?

Comment: Are abc.R and title.R stored in the same directory as global.R?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik what do you mean by a small reproducible example? as my server.R code is just the 2 line of source code. and the error is printed as above. Any more info that I can give?

Comment: @WannesRosiers, at first abc.R and title.R are not stored in the same directory, since I tried sourcing it directly from the path. However, I had copy the scripts over to be same directoryas global.R, server.R and ui.R.

Comment: By a reproducible example I mean provide code that generates .R files (scripts you're trying to source as well as server/ui) and sources them.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I tried adding one "short" version of my code, hopefully it will help.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I notice that when I source abc.R from itself, the variables appear in the global environment. When I source title.R then, new variables will appear, and the abc.R variables will be gone. Is there some problem here?

Comment: in source add local = TRUE: source("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Folder/abc.R",local=TRUE)
source("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Folder/title.R",local=TRUE)

Comment: @pops, tried, but cannot work as well.